# Oracle Virtualbox nologo still showing logo

Tags: command-line-interface, virtualbox

Hey all i am trying to figure out why the commands below are not working in order to remove the Oracle logo from the start (loading) of the VM...

Commands that I have tried:

> VBoxManage.exe -nologo startvm "myVMName"
>
> VBoxManage.exe --nologo startvm "myVMName"
>
> VBoxManage.exe -q startvm "myVMName"

[image]

Still the logo appears when it starts to boot the VM.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: any more questions? if it helps, you can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that "no-logo" means CLI's startup logo ( https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/342 )

To replace VM BIOS's splash screen:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "<VMname>" --bioslogoimagepath <imagepath>
```

This is documented in the VBox user manual: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvm

Answer (score 1):

I managed to hide the BIOS logo using the following commands. The `name` argument is the name of the virtual machine (VM) you want to modify.

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "<name>" --bioslogofadein off
VBoxManage modifyvm "<name>" --bioslogofadeout off
VBoxManage modifyvm "<name>" --bioslogodisplaytime 0
```

If you also want to disable the BIOS boot menu to further speed up the VM's start:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "<name>" --biosbootmenu disabled
```

For further details read the [documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvm).